# Content background to ignore parent container but text to maintain positioning

Tags: html, css

So I have a CSS issue that I can't seem to get my head around. I have solved this in a number of ways none of which seem to pass WCAG Axe accessibility tests as it mentions overlapping of elements.

I have some text whose position is correct, but I want the background-color of the text to span the whole width of the page without altering the position of the text.
Here's a simple example of the issue I want to solve.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">this is some text I want this text to be positioned here but the green background to span the whole width </p>
</div>
```

My solution involved an extra absolute div with the background set, but that didn't pass accessibility. Any pointers would be great, I appreciate I'm probably being silly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following settings to `.content`: `position: relative;` and `left: -50%;` to move its left side to the left border, and a left and right `padding` of 50% to make it wider/full width of its parent and keep the text contents aligned with the `.container` element:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">this is some text I want this text to be positioned here but the green background to span the whole width </p>
</div>
```

Note that the added `padding` would *not*  work if you somewhere have a `box-sizing: border-box` rule  for all your elements. In this case you'd have to add `box-sizing: content-box` to the `.content` rule to reset this parameter to its default.

Answer (score 1):

- You can achieve this by so many ways, here I have used `::before` pseudo element and without setting it's width apply `left:-100%` and `right:-100%`. Which is nothing but cover entire visible width.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.content::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">this is some text I want this text to be positioned here but the green background to span the whole width </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Axe still errors with: > Element's background color could not be determined due to a pseudo element

Comment: Could you please share the link you are using for validation?

Answer (score 1):

an idea using `border-image`

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  margin:0;
  border-image: conic-gradient(green 0 0) fill 0//0 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">this is some text I want this text to be positioned here but the green background to span the whole width </p>
</div>
```